# Congruence equation, I have no idea how to do it.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have here this equation:

$10x^{84} + 3x + 7 ≅ 0 (mod 35) $

I can't really do $y=x^{84}$ since I have a simple $x$ too, any other ideas? Thanks! :)

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem and Fermat's Little Theorem used together might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First notice that:
$$10x^{84}+3x+7\equiv 0 \mod 35$$
implies $5$ divides $3x+7$ and then $x=1 \mod 5$

But $7$ must divide $3x(x^{83}+1)$ hence $x\equiv 0 \mod 7$ or $x^{83}\equiv -1 \mod 7$ using Fermat's little theorem $x^{84}\equiv (x^{14})^6\equiv 1\mod 7$ hence $x^{83}\equiv x^{-1}$ we conclude that $x\equiv 0 \mod 7$ or $x\equiv -1 \mod 7$

Finally $x\equiv 21 \mod 35$ or $x\equiv 6 \mod 35$.

Comment: Error somewhere since you missed the solution $\,6.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque thank you for pointing out the error

Answer (score 1):

As $35=5\cdot7$

we need $10x^{84}+3x+7\equiv0\pmod7\ \ \ \ (1)$ and $10x^{84}+3x+7\equiv0\pmod5\ \ \ \ (2)$

For $(1),x(10^{83}+3)\equiv0\pmod7$

$\implies$ either $x\equiv0\pmod5\ \ \ \ (3)$

or $(x,7)=1\implies x^6\equiv1\implies x^{84}=(x^6)^{14}\equiv1^{14}$
$\implies10+3x\equiv0\pmod7\iff3x\equiv-10\equiv-3\iff x\equiv-1\equiv6\pmod7(4)$

Similarly  for $\pmod5,3x+7\equiv0\pmod5\iff3x\equiv-7\equiv3\iff x\equiv1\ \ \ \ (5)$

Then apply [CRT](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChineseRemainderTheorem.html) on $(3),(5);$ and $(4),(5);$